# Url variables AJAX

Tags: ajax, variables, url

***Disculpen tengo una duda como puedo mandar las mismas variables a dos url diferentes en un ajax***

Comment: Hola @JV93, Primero, considera hacer el [recorrido] cuanto antes. Segundo, considera editar tu pregunta y escribir lo que has intentado hasta el momento y explicar porque no ha funcionado. Tercero, considera [visitar el centro de ayuda] y aprender como funciona esta pagina de preguntas y respuestas. De no hacer esto y editar tu pregunta para bien, es posible que sea cerrada muy rapido.

Comment: Muy bien ..

Answer (score 1):

Podrías recorrer un arreglo usando la función $.each

```
var url = ['miurl1','miurl2', ....];

$.each(url, function( index, value ) {
  $.ajax({
        url: value,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
         },
         success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
         }
});
});
```

Considero que así debería funcionarte sin problema, al mismo tiempo no podías hacerlo, siempre debe hacerse por llamadas diferentes, ya que ajax solo puede hacer una llamada.

Saludos.